# MySQL, WHERE to contain separate table

Tags: mysql

I've managed to get the first part of my query working fine, it's the final part with the date check that is throwing me.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE available LIKE 'Yes' AND users.id NOT IN (SELECT player_id FROM match_request WHERE club_id LIKE '1000000003') AND (clubs.match_date >= CURRENT_DATE() WHERE clubs.id LIKE '1000000003')
```

It's this part that I can't work out:

```
(clubs.match_date >= CURRENT_DATE() WHERE clubs.id LIKE '1000000003')
```

I get the error message

> "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE clubs.id LIKE '1000000003') LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1"

But I don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace  `where` with `and`

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE available LIKE 'Yes' 
AND users.id NOT IN 
(
   SELECT player_id 
   FROM match_request 
   WHERE club_id LIKE '1000000003'
) 
AND clubs.match_date >= CURRENT_DATE() 
AND clubs.id LIKE '1000000003'
^^^-----here
```

and you need to join the `clubs` table if you  refer to any columns of that table

Comment: Thank you so that fixed the syntax error, however it is saying it doesn't recognise the clubs.match_date column (I have checked it is definitely there!)

Comment: I just see that you don't join the `clubs` table at all

Comment: Perfect! Just joined them and works. Spot on, thanks for your help :)